# Updating windows xp hard drive controller from ubuntu live disk

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp

The problem:

When booting, I get a blue screen shortly after the Windows XP logo splash screen. The error code is 7b, and the second hex number is 0xC0000034. Based on this [link](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/stop0x0000007b.htm) (item 7) it appears the driver should be updated.

Oddly, I made no changes to the drivers recently. I suspect it was something in a windows update or the newest upgrade of my antivirus (eset). But I digress.

The BSOD makes me unable to boot into Windows at all, so I can't update the driver from there. I've run various bios-level diagnostics (including full surface scan) and the hd looks good. I'm also able to boot to an old ubuntu disk and read files from the hd.

Update 1: "unable to boot into Windows" includes Safe Mode with and without networking/commmand prompt, as well as the Last Known Good State option.

The question:

Based on the above, it appears that I need to update the Windows hard drive controller from the ubuntu live disk. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It would be very difficult, if not impossible, to install a Windows driver manually through a Linux environment.

Your best bet is to try Safe Mode, and if that doesn't work, do a [repair](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/138-how-to-repair-windows-xp/):

> 1. Rule out hardware issues. Windows Repair will only fix software problems. Hardware issues can also cause boot problems (i.e. bad hard drive, memory, CPU, or power supply).
> 2. Backup. It's always a good idea to backup your important data before making changes to Windows XP. Relax, if you follow these instructions your data will be perfectly safe.
> 3. Boot from your Windows XP CD. Insert the Windows XP CD into your computer's CD-ROM or DVD-ROM drive, and then restart your computer. When the "Press any key to boot from CD" message appears on the screen, press a key to start your computer from the Windows XP CD. Can't boot from your CD? Please see the note at the bottom of this page (Configuring Your Computer to Boot from CD).
> 4. A blue screen will appear and begin loading Windows XP Setup from the CD.
>
> **Note:** RAID/SCSI/Unsupported UDMA users:
>
> You will be prompted to "press F6 to install any third party SCSI or RAID drivers". Most users will not have to press F6, but if you are running RAID, SCSI or unsupported UDMA controllers, then you will have to have your controller drivers on a floppy disk. If you are unsure whether you have RAID/SCSI, then simply let the CD load without pressing F6.
>
> When completed loading files, you will be presented with the following "Windows Setup" screen, and your first option. Select "To set up Windows XP now, press ENTER". DO NOT select Recovery Console.

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed a problem with a newer driver and you did not manually disable system restore then you should be able to boot info safe mode (via F8) and revert to an earlier driver.

Doing this manually from a live CD (Linux or otherwise) is non trivial. *1

*1: that is the non trivial profs use to throw you in university. Usually it means 'do not bother trying this'